# Firebase connectivity problem; the message port closed before a response was received

Tags: javascript, html

I  just created a form to connect it with firebase but getting a constant error. the message port closed before a response was received.

I have tried 2-3 codes but the same error is going on again and again.

```js
function writeToDatabase() {
event.preventDefault();
const n = document.getElementById("test1").value;
const p = document.getElementById("test2").value;

console.log(n + " "+ p);

firebase.database().ref('users').push().set({
test1: n,
test2: p,
});

alert("Stored");
}
```

```html
<div>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="test1">
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="test2">
    <button type="submit" onclick="writeToDatabase()">Submit</button>

</div>
```

data should be stored. but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to obtain the firebase configuration from your account. Will look something like this.

```
 var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "api-key",
  authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "project-id",
  storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
};
```

After that in your script tag, you should initialise firebase before using it.

```
  <script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
      // ...
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
```